# Insert the result of a function inside a value while mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php

I have a function that calculate the difference between 2 dates.
It gives results like this : **event happened 6 years ago**

How can I put this function so that it can get every time the date from a column and give us the result (string) inside the variable `timedif` here :

```
.....
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 array_push($res, array(
 "postText"=>$row['postText'],
 "location"=>$row['location'],
 "timedif"=>humanTiming($row['time'])));     
 }

 //Displaying the array in json format 
 echo json_encode($res);
 }else{
            echo "over";
    }
```

the code above doesn't work

humanTiming function :

```
function humanTiming ($time)
{

    $time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment
    $time = ($time<1)? 1 : $time;
    $tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
    );

    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
        if ($time < $unit) continue;
        $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
        return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks correct to me, what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: What is the format of the data you retrieve from MySQL into $time variable?

Comment: @Shadow it is timestamp , I just found the solution , i just put strtotime() and everything works great : "timedif"=>humanTiming(strtotime($row['time']))